# Frame of UIImageView changes after setting new image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` which is instantiated with an low resolution thumbnail from core-data. After the view has been presented the loading of the high-res web version starts which will replace the original image in the `UIImageView`. The problem however is that the frame changes once the download of the high-res version completes. This can't happen because of the blur layer on top of the original image which will then be a smaller size then the original image. I use the following code:

```
let imageData = member.picture
if let imageData = imageData {
    let image = imageFromData(imageData)
    
    // Setup pictures
    self.profilePicture.image = image
    self.profilePictureBlurred.image = image
    self.profilePictureBlurred.clipsToBounds = true
    
    // Make profilePicture round
    let width = self.profilePicture.frame.width
    self.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = width * 0.5
    self.profilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.profilePicture.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    self.profilePicture.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    
    // Blur profilePictureBlurred
    
    // Create Effects
    let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
    let vibrancy = UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blur)
    let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
    effectView.frame = self.profilePictureBlurred.frame
    let vibrantView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancy)
    vibrantView.frame = self.profilePictureBlurred.frame
    
    print(self.profilePictureBlurred.frame)
    
    // Add effects to profilePictureBlurred
    self.profilePictureBlurred.addSubview(effectView)
    self.profilePictureBlurred.addSubview(vibrantView)
    
    let iPid = Int(member.iPid!)
    getImageForPerson(iPid, completionHandler: { (image,error) in
        
        if error == nil {
            self.profilePicture.image = image
            self.profilePictureBlurred.image = image
            
            print(self.profilePictureBlurred.frame)
            
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    
    })
    
} else {
    print("No Image Data")
}
```

The size of the frame changes after the download completes, printlog:

> (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 150.0)
>
> (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 167.0)

This means that the blur effect no longer covers the entire UIImageView thus resulting in an ugly effect. Why does the UIImageView change size and what should be the correct way to set an image in a UIImageView for a second time?

The goal is to create something like the [LinkedIn contact view](http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple69/v4/1f/f5/27/1ff52744-eb96-cda1-af3f-381bfa185017/screen322x572.jpeg)

Edit: The outlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var profilePictureBlurred: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var profilePicture: UIImageView!
```

Comment: `self.profilePicture` points to the instance of `UIImageView`? Is the completion handler executed on the main thread?

Comment: See the edit: It points to an @IBOutlet of UIImageView. I don't know about the completion handler, how can i check this?

Comment: put brake point into it. when it stopes, just check thread it was stoped. If there is something like apple.mainthread, than it's main thread

Comment: I used your method and it says that the closure is executed on the com.apple.main-thread so yes :-)